# How do I navigate to the page where a hyperlink goes to when it doesn't have an href?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data using web pages' xpath. However, I am having difficulty in navigating to the page where a link goes to because it uses **AngularJS's ng-click** directive. Based on [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), it evaluates an expression when clicked. In the page I'm trying to scrape, it uses the following code.

```
<a l-translate="view all" ng-click="tabsSwitching('downloads')" class="ng-isolate-scope">view all</a>
```

If my understanding is correct, the above anchor is trying to call a javascript method to go to the downloads tab. If so, is there a way for me to go to that downloads tab through xpath? Or is there a better approach for this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a javascript script for the clicking of the element:

```
document.evaluate("//a[text()='view all']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to that link by getting the element and clicking on it. There is no other way to get the href value of an anchor tag if it is not mentioned.

So you can try this:

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='view all']")).click();
```